# Do nails and hair continue to grow after death?

Tags: mortality, hair, nail

I've heard that nails and hair continue to grow even after death. Is this true or just a myth?

Comment: Funny, I could have sworn this was a duplicate, but I can't find one.

Comment: Before and even while typing the question I was also thinking the same!

Answer (score 83, accepted):

### No, this is false.

The [University of Arkansas Medical Services](http://uamshealth.com/healthlibrary2/medicalmyths/dohairandnailsgrowafterdeath/) debunks this myth:

> Hair and fingernails may appear longer after death, but not because
>   they are still growing.  Instead, a persons fingernails and hair may
>   appear longer because the skin around them has retracted, according to
>   the Dermatology Clinic at UAMS.
>
> After death, dehydration causes the skin and other soft tissues to
>   shrink. This occurs while the hair and nails remain the same length.
>   This change in the body creates the optical illusion of growth people
>   observe.

The [BBC](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20130526-do-your-nails-grow-after-death) also makes a similar debunking:

> So why do myths persist about stubble growing on dead men’s chins and
>   fingernails lengthening? While such observations are false, they do
>   have a biological basis. It is not that the fingernails are growing,
>   but that the skin around them retracts as it becomes dehydrated,
>   making them appear longer. When preparing a body, funeral directors
>   will sometimes moisturise the fingertips to counteract this.

Comment: I thought everyone knew this, but perhaps not!